# Need a regex where two different substrings must not be included in a string

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following strings:

```
$string = @(
  'Get-WindowsDevel'
  'Put-WindowsDevel'
  'Get-LinuxDevel'
  'Put-LinuxDevel'
)
```

Now I need one regex with the following two rules:

1. `$string` must not start with "Get-"
2. `$string` must not contain "Linux"

This exclude the "Get-" at the beginning:

```
PS C:\> $string | Where-Object { $_ -match "^(?!Get-).*" }
```

> Put-WindowsDevel 
>  Put-LinuxDevel

I would expect that the following command does not match "Put-LinuxDevel" but it does:

```
PS C:\> $string | Where-Object { $_ -match "^(?!Get-).*(?!Linux)" }
```

> Put-WindowsDevel 
>  Put-LinuxDevel

So, what I need is a regex that is valid for this string only:

> Put-WindowsDevel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use `-notmatch`** (or, if case-*sensitive* matching is needed, `-cnotmatch`) - i.e., **a *negated* match** - in combination with alternation (`|`):

```
PS> $string -notmatch '(^Get-|Linux)'
Put-WindowsDevel
```

- The `-match` operator and its variations (as well as many other operators) can directly act on *arrays* as the LHS, in which case the operator acts as a *filter* and returns only matching elements.

  - Using `-match` on an array is much faster than using the `Where-Object` *cmdlet* in a pipeline for filtering.
- Regex `(^Get-|Linux)` matches *either* `Get-` at the start of the string (`^`) *or* (`|`) substring `Linux` anywhere in the string.
  Therefore, this regex matches strings that you *don't* want, and by using the *negated* form of `-match` - `-notmatch` - you therefore *exclude* those strings, as desired.

---

If you really want to **express your regex as a *positive* match**:

```
PS> $string -match '^(?!Get)((?!Linux).)*$'
Put-WindowsDevel
```

Note, however, that not only is this regex much more complex, it will also perform worse (albeit only slightly).

---

As for **what you tried**:

The `.*(?!Linux)` part of your regex - involving a [negative lookahead assertion (`(?!...)`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - is not effective at excluding strings that contain substring `Linux`; e.g.:

```
PS> 'Linux' -match '.*(?!Linux)'
True # !!
```

The reason is that `.*` matches the entire string and *then* looks ahead to see if `Linux` isn't there - which is obviously true at the end of the string.

**To effectively rule out a substring, the assertion must be applied around *each character* of the *entire string***:

```
PS> '', 'inux', 'Linux', 'a Linux', 'aLinuxb' -match '^((?!Linux).)*$'
                  # '' (empty string) matched
inux              # 'inux' matched
```

Note how `'Linux'`, `'a Linux'`, and `'aLinuxb'` were correctly excluded.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to do what you seek [*grin*] ...

```
$StringList = @(
    'Get-WindowsDevel'
    'Put-WindowsDevel'
    'Get-LinuxDevel'
    'Put-LinuxDevel'
    )

$ExcludeList = @(
    '^get'
    'linux'
    )
$RegexExcludeList = $ExcludeList -join '|'

$StringList -notmatch $RegexExcludeList
```

output ...

```
Put-WindowsDevel
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right, that would work but is there a way to define the regex string as one single string that works with "-match" (not "-notmatch)? The reason is that I read that regex string from a config file (json) together with alot of other regex strings and not all of them are "notmatches"

Comment: @MichaelHellmann - if you are doing this in PoSh, you can chain as many `-match` &  `-notmatch` operations as you want. [*grin*]

Comment: Just for safety's sake, when I do this I usually escape the strings like: `$RegexExcludeList = ($ExcludeList|%{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'`, just in case there are any reserved characters in one of the excluded strings.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - that clobbers the `^` in the 1st string. is there some way to avoid that?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: No; in this case you must craft the array entries as valid regexes to begin with (which requires `\ `-escaping metacharacters you want treated literally - not the case here).

Comment: @mklement0 - thank you [*grin*] ... i will leave out mentioning `[regex]::Escape()` then.

Comment: mklement0 is (as usual) correct. There's no way to avoid escaping the `^` in the `^get` string. I'll leave my comment for future readers that are going to just search for strings, not actual regex patterns.